# How to display data from database with a specific limit data showing?

Tags: php

hi guy's i need help from you..
i have a problem while selecting data from database with a specific limit data that i need to show or display. i want to display data between 40 to 80 but when the data displaying, the data that showing is from 40 to 81( and it can reach more of 81). 
i use this function to select that data.

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","silo");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


// Data for Titik1
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM temp2 LIMIT 40, 78");
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You need data from id between 40 and 80?

Comment: yeah... but its has done now.. i got solution from Saili Jaguste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query needs some corrections. Go through this tutorial for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

If you want to get records from 40 to 80 then your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM temp2 LIMIT 39, 41
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM temp2 LIMIT 39, 40` ? yours will return one additional row.

Comment: @Himal 40 to 80 results 41 records and 41 to 80 results 40 records